# android spinner if some item selected other spinner appear from derivative spinner 1

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have database with 2 tables

first table

```
id       jenis_barang
1        kamera
2        hp 
3        laptop
```

second table

```
id        item_barang
1         Canon
1         sony 
1         fujifilm
2         xiaomi
2         Samsung
2         Vivo
2         opppo
3         Asus
3         Toshiba
3         Acer

Spinner a =  Kamera, Hp, Laptop
Spinner b =  Canon, Sony, Fujifilm, xiaomi, Samsung, Vivo, Oppo, Asus, Toshiba, acer
```

I try to search with button based on id and I'm success,
and my trouble is, if I selected spinner 1, example I selected "kamera" and   spinner 2 show just same id based on "kamera".

```
    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String search =  searchdata.getText().toString().trim();
            setSpinner1 (search);
            setSpinner2 (search);
        }
    });


    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });


    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

// set spinner pertama (1)
public void setSpinner1(String kode) {
    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
    String query1 = "select namabarang from Jenis_Barang ";  //where id = '"+kode+"'
    Log.e("query",""+query1);
    try {
        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query1);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString(1);
            data.add(id);
            Log.e("idun",""+id);
        }
        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        spinner1.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("errora",""+e.getMessage());
    }

}


//set spinner ke dua
public void setSpinner2(String kode) {
    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
    String query2 = "select * from Item_Barang "; //where id = '"+kode+"'
    Log.e("query",""+query2);
    try {
        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query2);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString(2);
            String kodeBarang = rs.getString(4);
            data.add(id + " - " + kodeBarang);
            Log.e("ijah",""+id);
        }

        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        spinner2.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```